# Where is log file in openmeeting

Tags: java, drupal, openmeetings

I am using Drupal openmeeting module, which is written in the JAVA language and i am not getting the way out to debug.

I am new to Drupal so please do help me.

I tried to use `System.out.println()` and also tried to track in the error log but it din't help in any manner.

```
log.error("[screenSharerAction]", err);
```

The above code is used to recognize the error which is return in catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using openmeeting and in the root of the application i've a folder called "root". there is the log files.